# Unable to webscrape HTML table with BeautifulSoup and load it into a Pandas dataframe with Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My objective is to access the table on the following webpage https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/world-currencies.html and turn it into a Pandas dataframe that has columns "Country or territory", "Currency", and "ISO-4217".

I am able to access the columns correctly, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to append each row to a dataframe. Do you all have any suggestions on how I can do this? For example, on the webpage, the first row in the table is the letter "A". However, I need the first row in the dataframe to be `Afghanistan`, `Afghan afghani`, and   `AFN`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
url = "https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/world-currencies.html"
req = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
webpage=urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", {"class":"codes"})
rows = table.find_all('tr')
columns = [v.text for v in rows[0].find_all('th')] 
print(columns) # ['Country or territory', 'Currency', 'ISO-4217']
```

Please see this image as well.

[image]

Thank you all for your time.

Tony

Comment: Might want to check `response.status_code` - I get a 403 Forbidden from that site, so `response.text` won't have anything useful in it.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into it. I see now.

Comment: I resolved the bad request. Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your fix in place, it's something that can be pretty easily parsed by `pd.read_html`:

```
url = "https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/world-currencies.html"
req = Request(url, headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

df = pd.read_html(webpage)[0]
print(df.head())

         Country or territory        Currency ISO-4217
0                           A               A        A
1                 Afghanistan  Afghan afghani      AFN
2  Akrotiri and Dhekelia (UK)   European euro      EUR
3     Aland Islands (Finland)   European euro      EUR
4                     Albania    Albanian lek      ALL
```

It has those alphabet headers, but you can get rid of those with something like `df = df[df['Currency'] != df['ISO-4217']]`